# Custom data search within an array

Tags: stormpath, express-stormpath

Is it possible to search an account's custom data to find a value contained in an array?

Something like:

```
?customData.[arrayName].{key}=value
```

The [Stormpath docs](https://docs.stormpath.com/rest/product-guide/latest/reference.html#search-customdata) don't mention array searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for custom data in an array can definitely be done.  The syntax is: `customData.{fieldName}\[{index}\]=value` where `{index}` can be the specific index you are looking for, or `*` if you want to find it anywhere in the array.  (Note that the `[]` characters are escaped with a backslash or the query interpreter gets it confused with a range query.)

If you leave off the index entirely, then `\[*\]` is implied.  More precisely, Stormpath will check for *either* the value in the `fieldName` *or* the value as an element in an array of `fieldName`.  However, syntactic sugar can only work if the array field is the last element in your search.  Since you can put literally any JSON object into your custom data, Stormpath cannot check every single possibility.  Imagine something like `customData.foo.bar.baz.qux=bingo`.  Stormpath would not try to guess that maybe `foo` is an array, maybe `bar` is an array or not, maybe `baz` is an array or not - only maybe `qux` is an array or not.  So, if you want to search an array of objects, you cannot leave out the `\[*\]`.

Here is an example.  I have an account with the custom data:

```
{
  "favoriteThings": [
    {
      "thing": "raindrops",
      "location": "on roses"
    },
    {
      "thing": "whiskers",
      "location": "on kittens"
    },
    {
      "thing": "snowflakes",
      "location": "on my nose and eye lashes"
    }
  ],
  "favoriteColors": [
    "blue",
    "grey"
  ]
}
```

The following queries will yield the following results:

- `customData.favoriteColors=blue` will include this account.
- `customData.favoriteColors\[1\]=blue` will *not* include this account because `blue` is not at index 1.
- `customData.favoriteThings\[*\].thing=whiskers` will include this account
- `customData.favoriteThings\[*\].thing=ponies` will not include this account because it does not list ponies as one of his favorite things, but may include other accounts with custom data in the same structure.
- `customData.favoriteThings.thing=whiskers` would not include this account or any other accounts with the same custom data structure because in that case, Stormpath would be looking for a single nested JSON `favoriteThings` object, not an array.

Comment: \\[*\\] did it, thanks! Definitely worth adding to the docs :-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, with [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/) it is totally possible to search for custom data even if the values are stored as an array!

Please note that the field names are simple names, and the values are what are different data types like array, map, string etc... so the query is not as complex as one would think :-)

For example, if I want to store custom data called `favoriteColors`, which is an array like

```
"favoriteColors": [ "red", "black", "blue", "white" ]
```

Notice the field name is just like any other field name. The value is the array.

To search for accounts which have a value `red` in the `favoriteColors` array, you just need the normal query syntax:

```
?customData.favoriteColors=red
```

The full request (if searching a Directory of accounts), might look like this:

```
https://api.stormpath.com/v1/directories/<directory_uid>/accounts?customData.favoriteColors=red
```

You could also do the same search on the Tenant resource to search tenant-wide (across all accounts):

```
https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/<tenant_uid>/accounts?customData.favoriteColors=red
```

This query would match an account that contains `red` in the `favoriteColors` array. If I changed the query to `?customData.favoriteColors=yellow` it would not match unless `yellow` was also added to the array.

Comment: Thanks rbhojan. What is the syntax if it is an array of objects and I want to search a field within the object?

Comment: I haven't tested that, but I think this would work.  If you had `"favoriteThings": [{"thing": "raindrops", "location": "on roses"}, {"thing": "whiskers", "location": "on kittens"}]`, then you could search for `customData.favoriteThings.thing=raindrops`.

Comment: Yes, so as mentioned by jhericks for all the objects (nested fields) you can go as deep as you want within the nested object(s) and search by simply appending the nested field name(s), separated by dot(.), for each level of nesting. So, as in the example above by jhericks, `customData.favoriteThings.thing=raindrops` or `customData.favoriteThings.location=on*` etc. should work.

Comment: Thanks @jhericks, I tried adding the `favoriteThings` data and trying the query but get no results. Your `favoriteColors` example did work though.

Comment: @conrad, so does that solve your problem, or are you still stuck?

Comment: @jhericks I'm still stuck! I tried adding the favoriteThings complex array and trying the query but it didn't work.